# jamaa smpp: several delivery_sm with same MessageId

Tags: c#, .net, sms, smpp

all.

I am trying to implement a test smpp solution using jamaa.smpp libraries v1.4.
It successfully sending SMS messages, but when running - it is getting several DeliverSm messages with the same MessageIDs.

I guess, there is a problem with sending DeliverSmResp messages to SMSC, but I am new to this and it can be wrong.

What can be the problem? What should I check?
Any ideas will be helpfull.

Thank you.
With regards, Yuriy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only instance where you would receive multiple deliver_sm containing the same message ID would be if you were to request intermediate delivery reports. One message can have several statuses throughout it's lifetime. One status may say the message is "InProcess" with an error code attached, absent subscriber for example. When the message is retried and successfully delivers to the phone you will receive a new deliver_sm containing the same message ID but with the new status.

It's common to have more than one deliver_sm for one single submit_sm. now I don't know what you're testing so difficult to say if the above is true for your case.

Comment: Hi, Kim.
Thank you for your answer.
I think it was because of debug manual step-to-step delays, so I got deliver_sm packages, but server didn't get from me deliver_sm_resp in time.
Without debugging I don't see any issues.

With regards, Yuriy.